# Python Plot 3d Sphere polar or cartesian coords?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have a set of Cartesian coords (x,y,z,r) which I have to use to plot circles in different planes and spheres.

My problem is to find out how can I plot3d the spheres. Do I need to convert cartesian coords into polar?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it will be much easier to use something like this: `from visual import *` and `ball=sphere(pos=vector(x,y,z),radius=r,color=color.green)`